# I need a one-line description for a Christian horror novel I'm writing

Tags: novel, horror

I need a one-liner description for the book I’m writing. There are three main characters, a brother and sister and a young man.  My book is a Christian horror novel. The sister must keep her surrogate family together as she tries to forget her family of origin. Her half-brother searches for his biological mother and wants a woman he can truly trust. At first, the demon-possessed man wants to get rid of the evil spirit but, he changes his mind and starts collaborating with the demon to destroy the siblings. Example of a One line description: The Day of the Jackal, by Frederick Forsyth, “a thriller about a professional assassin hired by French terrorists to kill Charles de Gaulle.”

Comment: We can't do this for you. But, we can point you to websites about writing log lines. There are plenty of blogs out there. Google is your friend. My crack at it: "a Christian horror about a demon destroying an already broken family..."  <- See? It's not what you want. You need to find it yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appears to be about what to write rather than how to write. If _Tiny Bookworm_ wants to create a new questions asking how to come up with a one-line description, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Hell has come for the [Surname]'s!

It's short, sweet, but edgy enough to grab a millennial's attention.